# How do I remind Office 2011 on my Mac that I gave it a product key?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, microsoft-office-2011

I have a MacBook Pro with Microsoft Office 2011. When I migrated from my previous computer, I kept Office on both computers, purchasing a key when prompted on the new computer. That was several months ago.

This morning I went to open a Word document a friend gave me, and it gave a small black window and asked for a product key.

I can probably find the product key in my email archives, but I basically wanted to know why Office suddenly decided that it needs a new key, and if possible how to tell it "I purchased and gave you the product key you wanted; please get back to work."

---

The product key is one I have only used on this computer, and it worked when I re-entered it.

Comment: Unless you provide more information what you were doing before this happen the best solution is just to input the product key again.

Comment: @Ramhound, thank you; it was satisfied when I re-entered the product key.

Comment: Did your hard disk fill up completely?

Comment: No, my disk was nowhere near full.

Comment: The product key is one I have only used on this computer, and it worked when I re-entered it.

Answer (score 2):

Office 2011 Home and Student only allows it to be active on one computer at a time unless you purchase the three-license family pack. It probably stopped working because you started your other computer up. You didn't even need to launch office on the old computer to make the problem come up -- there's a daemon that runs in the background (/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.microsoft.office.licensing.helper.plist) that checks your license information to ensure you're running a valid copy.

Unfortunately, to fix the issue you're going to have to put in the product key on the new computer and remove it from the old one.